# How to verify context.data against a model schema in feathersjs?

Tags: mongoose-schema, feathersjs

For a complex service in feathersjs which requires validation on multiple models what is the way forward?

Assume a service named `uploads` which needs to verify the `POST` data against an existing mongoose model. How do we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by calling the service which uses the mongoose model to validate its `create` method. I guess my question is a bit confusing and now my answer seems to be another layer of confusion. Here is a drawing.

[image]